# porque me sale Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\admin\checklogin.php on line 8

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $usuario=$_POST['username'];
    $contrasena=$_POST['password'];

    include("../library/config.php");

    $ingreso = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM administrador WHERE Usuario='$usuario' AND Clave='$contrasena' ");
    if ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($ingreso)) {
        $_SESSION['u_username'] = $username;
        //header("location: paneladmin.php");
        echo "secion exitosa puto";
    }else{
        //header("location: index.php");
        echo "secion exitosa puto";
    }
?>
```

esta es de la conexion

```
<?php
    $usuario = "root";
    $password = "";
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $basededatos = "remate";

    // creación de la conexión a la base de datos con mysql_connect()
    $conexion = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, $password ) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");

    // Selección del a base de datos a utilizar
    $db = mysqli_select_db( $conexion, $basededatos ) or die ( "Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos" );
    mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: Buenas, por favor, formatea tu pregunta para que sea más legible, edita el contenido de tu pregunta para explicar exactamente cuál es tu problema (preferiblemente no pongas tu error tal cual en el título de la pregunta) y añade el código y los datos con los que estás trabajando para que pueda entenderse todo un poco mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Si en el fichero de conexión config.php cierras la conexión al final:

```
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Es normal que luego en tu fichero no vaya el query, pues lo haces sobre un recurso ya cerrado. Prueba a comentar la línea con // delante de la misma:

```
// mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Debería funcionar.